# React way of setting click handler event on element but not its children

Tags: reactjs

When setting the onClick event in the following way:

```
<button type="button" field={this.props.name} onClick={this.props.add_item}>
<i className="fa fa-plus"></i>
</button>
```

In the end I want to get the field attribute from the event target.

Now the problem: When I click on the button area i'll get the field attribute, but when clicked the child it also triggers the event but from a different target element (it has no field attribute; ...which I could set of course). But isn't there a better way to make the whole element trigger from the same target or something like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use [event.currentTarget](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget) instead of `event.target`

Answer (score 0):

You can make the parent click handler to be fired on clicking both the child and parent by binding another click handler in the child element calling `event.stopPropagation()`.
If you are using new browsers, then applying the following CSS to your `<i>` element should solve the problem:

```
pointer-events: none;
```

See [browser compatibility](http://caniuse.com/#feat=pointer-events).